# kadmind fails to start

Tags: kerberos, kdc

I am in the wake of setting up ad MIT Kerberos5 kdc on a Raspberry Pi 2.

As being a noob in such matters, I spent quite a fair number of hours on The Net, reading various documents, blogs, posts, forum entries, which helped really a lot.

Presently I am trying to get kadmind up and running, which unfortunately I am struggling with. In the corresponding log file it is reading something like

```
May 19 18:12:00 MyKdc-01 kadmind[3412](info): No dictionary file specified, continuing without one.
May 19 18:12:00 MyKdc-01 kadmind[3412](info): setting up network...
May 19 18:12:00 MyKdc-01 kadmind[3412](info): setsockopt(9,IPV6_V6ONLY,1) worked
May 19 18:12:00 MyKdc-01 kadmind[3412](info): setsockopt(11,IPV6_V6ONLY,1) worked
May 19 18:12:00 MyKdc-01 kadmind[3412](Error): Address already in use - Cannot bind server socket on 0.0.0.0.749
May 19 18:12:00 MyKdc-01 kadmind[3412](Error): Failed setting up a RPC socket (for 0.0.0.0.749)
May 19 18:12:00 MyKdc-01 kadmind[3412](Error): Address already in use - Error setting up network
```

My /etc/krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = MYDOM.LOCAL

    kdc_timesync = 1
    ccache_type = 4
    forwardable = true
    proxiable = true

    fcc-mit-ticketflags = true

[realms]
    MYDOM.LOCAL = {
        kdc = mykdc-01.mydom.local:88
        admin_server = mykdc-01.mydom.local:749
        default_domain = mydom.local
    }
[domain_realm]
    .local = MYDOM.LOCAL
```

and my /etc/krb5kdc/kdc.conf

```
[kdcdefaults]
    kdc_listen = 88
    kdc_tcp_listen = 88

[realms]
    MYDOM.LOCAL = {
    kadmind_port = 749
    max_life = 10h 0m 0s
    max_renewable_life = 7d 0h 0m 0s
    master_key_type = des3-hmac-sha1
    default_principal_flags = +preauth
    database_name = /var/lib/krb5kdc/principal
    admin_keytab = FILE:/etc/krb5kdc/kadm5.keytab
    acl_file = /etc/krb5kdc/kadm5.acl
    key_stash_file = /etc/krb5kdc/stash
}

[logging]
    kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5/krb5kdc.log
    admin_server = FILE:/var/log/krb5/kadmin.log
    default = FILE:/var/log/krb5/krb5lib.log
```

### Any hint as how to tackle this one would be more than appreciated. :)

C.

Comment: `Address already in use` means something is already running and using that port. Only one thing at a time can listen on the port. I'd guess you have another instance of kadmind running. `netstat -tulpn` will definitively tell you what process is listening on any port.

Comment: Thanks! There was indeed some service occupying the port.